# Matlab circle packing on a sphere

Tags: matlab

I am trying to pack same-radi circles on a sphere using matlab. I have figured out how to pack circles and spheres in a box or a cube but just can't figure out where to start when packing it on the surface of a sphere. I would love any hints or ideas in doing this.

Wish you all the best of luck

Comment: This is a really hard problem, not sure if there exists a generic solution. I bet the people that downvoted your question were annoyed to find a question they didn't know an answer to. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really hard problem, not sure if there exists a generic solution.

To obtain perfectly regular distribution of circles, take any [regular polyhedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polyhedron), and put a circle at each vertex. The largest regular polyhedron, the [dodecahedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron) has 20 vertices, so you would be able to fit 20 circles on a sphere with this method. If you are willing to have a tiling that is not perfectly regular, you can use shapes such as that of a [buckyball](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene) (same as soccer ball).

Other ways to distribute points evenly around a sphere have been proposed.

A friend of mine proposed a way that allowed him to easily index each point. It was based on the icosahedron (dual of the dodecahedron, it has 20 faces), and tiled each triangular face. See [his paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2901733_3D-Orientation_Space_Filters_and_Sampling) for more details.

That paper has references to some other methods known at that time. I think the most useful one would be the one where the sphere is cut vertically into slices of equal width (the surface of the sphere section has equal height, the cuts themselves are not spaced evenly), and each section is then a strip that can be tiled by circles evenly. This leads to one circle on the top and one on the bottom, and in between rows of circles. The distribution is not even, and the spacing depends on the ratio of the circle size and sphere size.